# indent algorithmic outside of a block

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx

I want to change the horizontal position of the complete code. Remove the padding if you will. How can I do that?

```
\begin{algorithm}[t!]
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{.1em}%
\caption{With intent no indent}
    \begin{algorithmic}%\
    \Function{\publish[$c, data$]}{}
        \State{algorithmicindent works inside this block only}
    \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}%\
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show an MWE. I do not know the packages which are needed here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) sets up the entire `algorithmic` environment *list* structure at the start of the environment. It assumes there will be some line numbering and therefore leaves some horizontal indent. If you're never going to use line numbering you can just make `\leftmargin`, `\labelwidth` and `\labelsep` to `0pt` using an [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) of `\algorithmic`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}{\ALG@tlm\z@}{\ALG@tlm\z@\leftmargin 0pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{With intent no indent}
  \begin{algorithmic}
  \Function{Publish[$c$, \textit{data}]}{}
    \State algorithmicindent works inside this block only
  \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The `\xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}` appends the setting of `\leftmargin 0pt` immediately after `\ALG@tlm\z@`. In the construction of the list, this happens just after all the list environment measurements have been set.

Here's a view of the `algorithmic` environment as defined in [`algorithmicx.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty), together with the location where the above `\xpatchcmd` inserts the code:

```
\newenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]%
   {%
   \edef\ALG@numberfreq{#1}%
   \def\@currentlabel{\theALG@line}%
   %
   \setcounter{ALG@line}{0}%
   \setcounter{ALG@rem}{0}%
   %
   \let\\\algbreak%
   %
   \expandafter\edef\csname ALG@currentblock@\theALG@nested\endcsname{0}%
   \expandafter\let\csname ALG@currentlifetime@\theALG@nested\endcsname\relax%
   %
   \begin{list}%
      {\ALG@step}%
      {%
      \rightmargin\z@%
      \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent2em%
      \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@%
      \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em%\skip 1.2em 
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}%
         {\labelwidth 0.5em}%
         {\labelwidth 1.2em}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}% Ok. the perfect leftmargin :-))
      \ALG@tlm\z@% <----- resetting of \leftmargin 0pt inserted here
      }%
   \setcounter{ALG@nested}{0}%
   \ALG@beginalgorithmic%
   }%
   {% end{algorithmic}
   % check if all blocks are closed
   \ALG@closeloops%
   \expandafter\ifnum\csname ALG@currentblock@\theALG@nested\endcsname=0\relax%
   \else%
      \PackageError{algorithmicx}{Some blocks are not closed!!!}{}%
   \fi%
   \ALG@endalgorithmic%
   \end{list}%
   }%
```